# Prompt before sending SMS Android

Tags: android, prompt

I am new in Android and I am attempting to Send an SMS through an Android application. I need it such that if the Message Contains the Word "MYSELF" Prompt the user whether they want to go ahead to send the SMS My Method is :

```
public void sendSmsByManager() {

        try {

            // Get the default instance of the SmsManager

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber.getText().toString(),
            null,
            smsBody.getText().toString(),
            null,
            null);
             //If the SMS Contains the WORD MYSELF Prompt the User If they Want to send the SMS

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Your sms has successfully sent!",

                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms has failed...",

            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want this to trigger when the user sends a text to himself,  when the user literally sends a message to "Myself" or simply when the message contains the text "myself"?

Comment: When the text Contains the Word "Myself"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Alert Confirmation style dialog.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Some Message");
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               //send text
           }
       });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               //discard text
           }
       });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Am sorry I do not get how do I incorporate that into My code? I am trying this for the First time :(

Comment: That would drop into your code where you send the text, and then in the onClick for the positive button you would move the send call.

Comment: I want text in the Prompt. like "SMS Contains MYSELF, DO YOU REALLY WANT TO SEND?"

Comment: Then use the setMessage method of Builder

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you :

```
public void sendSmsByManager() {
    try {

         //If the SMS Contains the WORD MYSELF Prompt the User If they Want to send the SMS
       if (smsBody.getText().toString().contains("MYSELF")){

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setMessage("SMS CONTAINS MYSELF! Do you really Want to send this SMS"); // It will set the message you want to display

            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Get the default instance of the SmsManager
                       SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                       smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber.getText().toString(),
                       null,
                       smsBody.getText().toString(),
                       null,
                       null);

                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                               "Your sms has successfully sent!",

                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       dialog.dismiss();

                   }
               });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

       }



    } catch (Exception ex) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your sms has failed...",

        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: This Brings the Prompt But There s no Text "SMS CONTAINS MYSELF! Do you really Want to send this SMS"?